# Are low shoes suitable for running?

Tags: running, running-shoes

I play basketball, and I would like to improve my running speed and resistance.

I obviously own a pair of basketball shoes, but I wouldn't like to use them outside the pitch to avoid degrading them quickly. I love low shoes and I own a pair of white Onitsuka Tiger, but now I use them only to play football on grass since they won't be clean anymore. I was thinking: can I use them to go running? Would my foot/ankle/leg be hurt if I do this? I'm asking because lots of people said me it's no good.

I went running with them once, but only for 20 minutes since it started raining so I don't know if it is good.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of factors that go into choosing a pair of running shoes. Running in "Low" shoes means you will not have any support. This means if you heal plant you will most likely get injured at some point. The longer you run the more you will find how you run.

Running on hard surfaces also will play a factor, if you run on grass it will be easier on your feet then running on concrete.

As you run longer you will also become more tired and more apt to heal plant. If you don't heal plant you will be running on the balls of your feet and the longer you run the more prone you will be to shin and achilles injuries.

You can go to any good running store and they will evaluate your running gait. From this you will find out if you pronate or supinate. If you run on your heal, toes or balls of your feet. From there you can decide if you can run in the shoes that you show in your picture.

So, to summarize:
1) Have someone at a running store evaluate your gait

2) Don't start with two many miles. Ease into it so you don't get injured

3) Remember to take days off

4) If you really like running you will discover you want to get a pair of running shoes for running.

Comment: Very complete answer, I'll follow your advices